# Make regular request and ajax request at same time asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a situation where I want to call two different controller methods at the same time when a user clicks on a link. One method is the action result method, and one is a method that is used for logging that should have no impact on the action result method. Is it possible to have a request to the actionResult method using a regular http request, and an ajax call to the logging method using an ajax at the same time?

Comment: Please show your code with your attempts, because your question is too broad and not specific enough. [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You can mention one on **href** and other on **Ajax**, Even then both action method doesn't execute together. if you use ajax and call second action method on the success of first, it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery to hijack the `click` event if the link and send the ajax request.

```
$(function(){

   $("#yourLinkId").click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();

      //make the ajax call here
      $.post("yourUrlForAjaxActionMethodHere");

      // and do the redirect to the url for which the link was clicked.
      window.location.href=$(this).attr("herf");

   });

});
```

Assuming your link has id "`yourLinkId`"

```
<a id="yourLinkId" href="/YourTargetUrl">Some link</a>
```

For any reason. if you absolutely prefer to get a success response from your ajax call before the navigation, you may do that in your `$.post` method success callback

```
var url=$(this).attr("herf");
$.post("yourUrlForAjaxActionMethodHere",function(){
    window.location.href=url;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the action method cannot be called together, Hence its better to use ajax and call one action method on the success of another

```
<a onclick='someFunc()'>link</a>
```

**AJAX:**

```
function someFunc()
{

         $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: @url.action('firstActionMethod','controller'),
                success: function(data) {
                            $.ajax({
                               type: "POST",
                               url:   @url.action('SecondActionMethod','controller'),
                               success: /*SUCCESS CODE*/
                                 });
                       }
              });
}
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't want the logging method to have any impact on the user experience. So the logging doesn't need to rely on the success of the regular ActionResult method and vice versa